# PERMISSION DENIED when using Firebase AppCheck in emulator suite

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools, firebase-app-check

I'm implementing AppCheck in my app in order to prevent bad access to Firestore. I activated the service in Firebase Console and add this line `await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();` after Firebase initialization.
Now, if I try to access Firestore in my app through emulator it logs `PERMISSION DENIED`.
How could I develop updates for my app and continue testing while AppCheck is enabled?

Comment: faccio, let me know if my recommendations were helpful or are you looking for some other information.

Comment: actually I don't understand if I have to implement Debug provider in a copy of the project or in the original project.

Comment: As mentioned, currently the Dart API does not have Debug Provider.You can check for other available platforms and implement the Debug provider to the App where you want to do App Check, usually not in Emulator or Continuous integration environment.

Answer (score 0):

After you have registered your app for App Check, your app normally won't run in an emulator or from a continuous integration (CI) environment, since those environments don't qualify as valid devices. If you want to run your app in such an environment during development and testing, you can create a debug build of your app that uses the [App Check debug provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider) instead of a real attestation provider.

Refer documentation [Flutter app Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider) details.
However, as per the documentation, the debug provider does not currently have a Dart API; you'll need to apply the changes separately for each of your platforms.

You may check the App Check debug provider available for other platforms like [Apple](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/debug-provider), [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/debug-provider) and [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/debug-provider).